# 1 jenkins job trigger multiple jenkins jobs based on parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any Jenkins plugin that helps with the following:

- if a directory `<XXX*`, is present in SVN folder `<GoRoCo>`
- then the `<GoRoCo>_<XXX>` Jenkins job is called
  ?

Example:
In job `"TEST"` , I specify parameters like directory name (A, B , C) and folder name (G1R2) then job `"TEST"` should trigger the jobs `"G1R2_A"` ,  `"G1R2_B"` and `"G1R2_C"`

Answer (score 4):

Use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). When specifying jobs to call in the plugin you can use tokens, as in `JOB_${PARAM1}_${PARAM2}`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at that plugin, i think it does exactly what you are looking for:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Files+Found+Trigger

Answer (score 2):

Use [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

With the help this plugin you can run as many jobs with or without parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use some scripts to create property file  with the required parameters for each of the modified project and place them in the workspace directory.

Later you can use parameterised plugin to trigger downstream project like this.

[image]

Note: you might also have to delete those properties after triggering the down stream projects.