# How to run job with each parameter jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a job configured in jenkins, that has 4-5 choice parameter. Till now we used  to do "build with parameter"-> select one of the parameters and run the job.

Now a new requirement has come, where, the same job has to be triggered with each of these parameters one by one.

I am quite new to jenkins, and could not find exact solution for this requirement. Looking for some help here.

Thanks.

Comment: It does not look straight forward though, you can try to have one job with all the parameters and trigger another job by passing each parameter. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704677/jenkins-passing-variables-between-jobs ..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810975/1-jenkins-job-trigger-multiple-jenkins-jobs-based-on-parameters

Comment: I used script posted by Gripsiden. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Pipeline to trigger ?

```
node{
 try{
      stage('1st Parameter') 
{
  build job: 'target_job_name_here', parameters: 
      [
      string(name: 'parameter_1', value: 'Parameter1-value')
      ]
}
 }    
   catch (err){
      echo "1st Parameter fail"
   }
 try{
      stage('2nd Parameter') 
{
  build job: 'target_job_name_here', parameters: 
      [
      string(name: 'parameter_2', value: 'Parameter2-value')
      ]
}
 }    
   catch (err){
      echo "2nd Parameter fail"
   }
 try{
      stage('3rd Parameter') 
{
  build job: 'target_job_name_here', parameters: 
      [
      string(name: 'parameter_3', value: 'Parameter3-value')
      ]
}
 }    
   catch (err){
      echo "3rd Parameter fail"
   }

}
```

Not sure if that would help?

Comment: I followed you suggestion, and used name variable same for all the three calls.:                                string(name: 'Value_Env', value: 'Parameter1-value')
string(name: 'Value_Env', value: 'Parameter2-value')

Created parameter in downstream job and used Value_Env as value of that.                        

It worked fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem , enjoy!